# Why datetime isocalendar transition back will shift 1 week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I start datetime.now() (today is 6/11) and transition to week day:

```
>>> now=datetime.now().isocalendar()
>>> now
(2019, 24, 2)
```

but when I transition back, I found it shift 1 week:

```
>>> res = datetime.strptime(now[0]+'_'+now[1]+'_'+now[2], "%Y_%W_%w")
>>> res 
datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 18, 0, 0)
```

can someone enplane it?
very thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from datetime import daytime

iso_string = str(now[0]).zfill(4) + '_' + str(now[1]).zfill(2) + '_' + str(now[2])
res = datetime.strptime(iso_string, "%G_%V_%u").date()
```

strptime has special directives for ISO week numbers: `"%G_%V_%u"`

From trying out, it seems like leading zeros don't really matter, but the [official standard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) says they do, so be sure to add them with `zfill()`.

This only works for python>=3.6, previous versions of `strptime` seem to be incompatible with ISO weeks.

For earlier versions of python, I think it is best practice to use the [isoweek module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/):

```py
from isoweek import Week

res = Week(now[0], now[1]).day(now[2]-1)
```

Comment: thanks,but i found that"%G_%V_%u" will show"does not match format" when weekday=0

Comment: That's intended, the standard says `1, 2, …, 7, where 1 is Monday`. That's exactly what your `isocalendar()` call returns. That's also why you need to add the `-1` for the isoweek library.